# Does Ubuntu come with dictionary/list of words file?

Tags: dictionary

I was wondering if Ubuntu comes with a file that lists all of the words in, say, the Webster's dictionary, for the purposes of spell checking and whatnot.

I looked around a bit and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The package `wamerican` has a word list for American English (installed in `/usr/share/dict/american-english`). There are dictionaries for other languages available, which you can find by searching the repositories for the desired language (e.g. `wbritish` has a word list for British English).

Comment: Anyone searching for a German wordlist: It's `wngerman`.

Comment: `wamerican-insane` has a lot of words. I used this to generate possible phone extensions.